# iOS shuffle icon like in the Music app

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How do I get this effect in a UITableViewCell? The icon placement is just to the right of the label.

Also, is this shuffle icon something that is standard which I should use? I have a similar application where the user can shuffle through words, each word will play in random order if they press this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the UIKit Artwork Extractor [1] to extract all the apple standard icons and use them in your application. Apple has no problem with this (so far).

[1] https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for this. And do you know how to position the icon as shown?

Answer (score 0):

(assuming u click that icon to shuffle the list)
its as simple as adding a custom button with that imageview as background , as subview to the cell.but set the frame accordingly like

```
UIButton *shuffbutton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        shuffbutton.frame=CGRectMake(100,5, 30, 30);
[shuffbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shuffle_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [shuffbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(shuffle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:shuffbutton];
```

Comment: Not that complicated. Still want the whole cell to be a button... just want the image to position to the right of the text (not all the way to the right)

Comment: in that case use an imageview ,as the shuffle text is static ,u know its length and can put the image just right to it ,and  as usual write the code to shuffle in didselectrowatindexpath method(and who said 100 pixels would make your image all the way to the right ,its just sufficient to cover your "shuffle" text only :) )